# Joomla - Hide part of a Responsive module on smaller resolutions (Mobiles)

Tags: php, css, joomla, responsive-design, joomla2.5

I am using a responsive Slideshow module - Lof ArticlesSlideShow (**[DEMO](http://landofcoder.com/demo/joomla25x/f33/modules/lof-articles-slideshow-module)**) .

How can I hide the "Navigator" part (the scrolling rows of articles with thumbnails) when I resize the window to a smaller size.

Right now, if I re-size the browser window to my mobile's display's size (Motorola Defy+), the navigator part will come over the image,title and introtext . Opened the demo link on the mobile browser and same effect.

Since the link to the article is on the title, which becomes hidden under the navigator, the article page cannot be accessed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to a custom CSS file or current one:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .lof-buttons-control {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This means that the maximum width of the screen, till this code starts to kick in is 480px. From then on, it hides the Navigator part.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

@Lodder - AMAZING!!!!!!!! :D

I replaced **`.lof-buttons-control`** with **`.lof-ass .lof-navigator`** and it worked :D

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.lof-ass .lof-navigator {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

It means a lot!!!!